# jQuery using .animate() fails to do ANYTHING in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jquery-animate

So, it's official:  I hate Internet Explorer.  Yes, all bloody versions of it.  :-D

So, I didn't think I was doing anything complicated here, but apparently I am.  I have a bunch of list items in an unordered list styled for a navigation menu, and in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera, things work fine.  What is supposed to happen is when you hover a navigational item, it should animate some growth and animate a background color change.

Nothing happens in Internet Explorer 7/8.

I think it's just tied to the animate function, since if I swap .animate with .css, it works.

http://project-cypher.net/wtf/ (*url removed - problem solved)

Ideas?

Comment: Teh codez seem to be this: http://pastebin.com/zjmrS9wJ

Comment: `So, it's official: I hate Internet Explorer. Yes, all bloody versions of it.`. What took you so long?

Comment: @ Lucas Jones: Yeah, that's the javascript that hooks the hover event and animates the anchor element.  Did I miss something or did you submit a correction to what I wrote?

Comment: @ The Elite Gentleman: No kidding... :-D

Comment: So what does it do in IE8? Nothing at all? No warnings or anything in the error console? On http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color there are a few IE related and pending bug reports. Check error console if one of those applies to you.

Comment: @jitter: Yes, nothing happens.  Literally.  No warnings in the dev console, no javascript errors... nothing.  I thought maybe the CSS I was applying via the script wasn't taking effect, which would be why the script appeared to not be working, but alas, via hard-coded CSS, the desired final effect was rendered (sans animation of course).  I'll check out that link and see if maybe the problem is with the color plugin, but I've also tried removing that plugin with the same results... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your animation properties a bit using `backgroundColor`, `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom`, this should work:

```
$('ul.navigation li a').css('padding','0px 12px');
$('ul.navigation li a').hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
      backgroundColor : '#336699',
      'padding-top': 6,
      'padding-bottom': 6
    }, 150 );
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({
      backgroundColor: '#660000',
      paddingTop: 0,
      paddingBottom: 0
    }, 150 );
});
```

This CSS:

```
ul.navigation li a {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #600;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets me closer.  The background color now fades in and out as it should.  The padding is still not applying though... I've tried as you've written it, also tried encapsulating the value in single quotes... so far nothing.

Comment: @Nick - Yes, no dice in IE7/8, good in other browsers.  I'm using jQuery 1.4.2.  Can't remember the version of the color plugin that overrides .animate(), but I did download that a few days ago.  Maybe I'll try grabbing a fresh, un-minified copy...

Comment: This is the version of the color animations plugin I'm using:

http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.color.js.txt

Still no go.  I wonder what's different between what you have working and what I have that isn't working...

Comment: @Cypher - I was wrong on my end, doesn't work on this computer with IE8....updated the answer with something that does, lack of padding allocated on page load seems to make it unable to animate, allocating then removing allows it.  Take a look here for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/py57F/

Comment: Yeah, that certainly did the trick!  I'm just glad IE supports conditional comments... thanks for the help Nick!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem myself, the other day. I couldn't figure out why IE didn't properly animate the objects.

The answer is simple, though: use [jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com)

jQuery UI includes an improved color plugin that *actually works*.

Check out the other neat things in jQuery UI while you're at it - buttons, dialogs, progress bars, tabs, etc.

Comment: Nice plug.  Really had nothing to do with it, but thanks anyway.

Comment: It does. jQuery UI has a color plugin that allows backgroundColor to be used in `animate`.

Answer (score 0):

If I change the 'padding' : '6px 12px ' to 'padding' : '12px' it seems to work. Can you try this and report if it doesn't work on your end?

It's not perfect but it does something, and gets you a little closer to fixing it.

EDIT: Dang, wonder why not. Worked here. IE8. IDK, maybe you've got the solution from the other answer.

Comment: Hrm, that doesn't seem to work in IE8.  Didn't test in 7... :)